# Why tests failing headlessly but not when browser is opened?

Tags: docker, cypress

I've got failing tests that are failing only when running headlessly:

`docker run -v $PWD:/e2e -w /e2e --network tdd_default cypress/included:4.11.0 --config baseUrl=http://nginx`

I get:

[image]

And I've got few more like this one. One thing in common is that `xhr` line which is the line
where the form sends details to the backend. It fails.

Tests pass when I run tests using Electron:

`./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --config-file cypress_dev.json`

The screenshot indicates that it is a networking issue but I use the same docker network in both scenerios.

How can I troubleshoot this ?

**Update:**

Debug mode revealed:

[image]

It's very likely a routing issue with Nginx.